# Google+1 Button with predefined text.

Tags: button, share, google-plus

Is there a possibility to have a Google+1 Button that shares a specific link with a predefined text (that can be edited by the user if preferred)?

(I've seen similar with Twitter-Tweet-Buttons with a predefined text.)

Answer (score 0):

The [+1 button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/) can both +1 and share a specific link. The preview for that share will display the page's title and an image (descriptions are no longer displayed). All of the data that Google+ uses comes from the "[snippets](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)" that it finds on the page when it crawls the page. The user is not able to edit the text, but if more than one thumbnail is available, the user can pick from available thumbnails.